# install joomla on strato.de

Tags: joomla, file-permissions

I am creating a website based on Joomla! for my german friend who has a hosting in strato.de
I encountered many problems with installing Joomla on this hosting. After uploading Joomla 1.5.23 files on their server and trying to install Joomla, I got anerror:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(.../configuration.php) [function.file-put-contents]:
failed to open stream:
Permission denied in /.../installation/installer/models/model.php on line 850
```

After this, I created manually configuration.php and filled it with database data (passwords etc).

Joomla seemed to be installed, but when I tried to install any extension, I can't do it since it shows only errors like:

```
Cound not create directory
Component install: failed to create directory
```

Of course I tried to change directory permissions to 777 but it didn't help, always the same problem and no availability to install any component. The php info shows it's a SunOs on the server and i think something is wrong with owner of the files.

I also tried to install Joomla via strato own installator, but it gives the same errors.
I contacted strato de help office, but they answer was "we do not offer any technical / scripting support for either of the 3rd party CMS's".

Could someone help me please with that?
Has anyone succeed with installing Joomla and components on this hosting?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should never set the permissions to anything to 777, that's a big security risk.

Next, chances are that the server is not configured properly to run Joomla without any problems. Joomla works a lot better when PHP is run in CGI mode rather than when it is run as an Apache module. Most likely the server you are on is running PHP as an Apache module, which causes a lot of issues.

You can get around a lot of the issues by turning on the FTP layer, but there are some things to check first -

1. Make sure that both the log and tmp directories exist in the root.
2. Check the directory permissions by logging in to the admin then Help > System Info > Directory Permissions (you should see the tmp and log directories here as well). Files should be 644, directories should be 755.
3. Turn on the FTP layer by going to Site > Global Configuration > Server > FTP Settings

If it still gives you errors, I would suggest moving to a better hosting company. Rochen Host has a data center in the UK and they handle all of the official Joomla websites. I use them and they are great. Everything works without any issues.